# adding one event listener within another, and waiting for dom to fully load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a class with a map marker which, when clicked, opens a pop up window which contains a button on it (which says "reserve").

I know that I can use

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        console.log("document loaded");
      });
```

but the problem is that that console log is never called. When I try to add the event listener to the button, as such:

```
marker.addListener("click", () => {
      this.reserveButton = document.getElementById("reserve");
      this.reserveButton.addEventListener("click", this.reserveFunction);
}
```

I get an error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`. This makes sense, since the script is being executed before the html loads. What is the best way to ensure the html loads first?

**edit : per discussion:**
component code:
to call modal this is the modal

```
openReserveModal: (order, vendor) => dispatch(openModal({ type: 'reserve', order: order, vendor: vendor }))
```

open reserve modal is then used in the constructor of marker manager

```
    this.MarkerManager = new MarkerManager(
      this.map,
      this.props.openReserveModal
    );
```

marker manager which handles data for marker (which when clicked opens popup)

```
  constructor(map, modal) {
    this.map = map;
    this.modal = modal;
    this.markers = {};
    this.openWindow = null;
    this.highlight = null;
    this.reserveButton = null;
    this.reserveFunction = null;
```

reserve div:

```
<div id="map-reserve" class="info-win-name info-win-reserve">
 RESERVE
</div >
```

reserve function:

```
      this.reserveFunction = () => {
        this.modal(order, vendor);
      };
```

Comment: Can't you use the react onClick method on the reserve button? https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Yeah, but for some reason I get a syntax error. The reserve function should call modal(order, vendor) where modal takes in an order and vendor object

my code looks like           <div id="map-reserve" onclick="this.modal(${order},${vendor})">

The error is specifically "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
and in the console, "this.modal([object Object],[object Object]) " has my objects underlined in red

Comment: Looks like you have some syntax error in that code in the comment. Could you add all the relevant component code to your question

Comment: @spirift added!